# How can I get my NSIS context menu options back after associating a program with .NSI files?

Tags: file-association, nsis

I associated .nsi files with a text editor recently, and as a result lost all of the special NSIS context menu options for, eg., "Compile NSIS Script".  How can I get them back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [a post on the NSIS forums](http://forums.winamp.com/showpost.php?p=2621325&postcount=5), I learned that when you associate a file extension manually, Explorer creates a registry key that overrides the system settings for that extension.  In the case of NSIS files, this key is:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.nsi

If you delete that key, you will lose your text editor association but regain the context menu items after restarting Explorer.

Comment: Ending all explorer.exe processes and starting it again did not do it for me. Had to restart the whole Windows.

Answer (score 1):

there's also a [script](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Windows_7_Cascading_Context_Menu) for that